# Check or verify authenticity_token in a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wondering what my options are to increase security in Rails 3. As an example, if I create a vanilla Rails 3 app and create a single model `Task` and single field `Name`. Then go to localhost:3000/tasks/new, inspect the page, and change the `authenticity_token` to "test" I am able to submit the form. If I do the same use case in a Rails 5 app I get the exception:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in TasksController#create
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
Extracted source (around line #195):
        def handle_unverified_request
          raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
        end
      end
    end
```

Looks like Rails 3 has a few additional CSRF related methods here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html will any of these address this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I watch the console I see `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` when I change `authenticity_token`. So Rails 3 knows that the token is not right, it's just not doing anything about it.

I found I can implement [handle_unverified_request](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#method-i-handle_unverified_request) by adding it to my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def handle_unverified_request
      raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
  end
end
```